# Generate an equivalent Hash value in Android/Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, android, sha

I am trying to construct a hash value in Android, that given the same result that generated from C#. Unfortunately, I cannot get the same hash value, may I know which part of my java code is wrong ? Any help is appreciated.

Below is my C# code, result = "0KRg7JtDNE/lkobY3OZqpzUAMgA2ADEA"

```
        string password = "5261";
        string passwordsalt = "0KRg7JtDNE/lkobY3OZqpw==";
        byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Password);
        //Output bIn bytes = { 53, 0, 50, 0, 54, 0, 49, 0, }

        byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(PassworldSalt);
        //Output bSalt bytes = {208, 164, 96, 236, 155, 67, 52, 79, 229, 146, 134, 216, 220, 230, 106, 167,}

        byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
        byte[] bRet = null;

        Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
        //Output bAll bytes = { 208, 164, 96, 236, 155, 67, 52, 79, 229, 146, 134, 216, 220, 230, 106, 167, 53, 0, 50, 0, 54, 0, 49, 0, }
        
        HashAlgorithm s = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
        bRet = s.ComputeHash(bAll);
        string newHash = Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
```

What i have tried in Android/Java code, result = "hgS6gq6s+8C8/BqVz2b9Ofanq0g=\n"

```
    String password= "5261";
    String salt = "0KRg7JtDNE/lkobY3OZqpw==";
    byte[] bIn   = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // Output bIn bytes = [53, 50, 54, 49]

    byte[] bSalt = Base64.decode(salt, Base64.DEFAULT);
    // Output bSalt bytes = [-48, -92, 96, -20, -101, 67, 52, 79, -27, -110, -122, -40, -36, -26, 106, -89]

    byte[] bAll  = new byte[bSalt.length + bIn.length];
    byte[] bRet  = null;
    System.arraycopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.length);
    System.arraycopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.length, bIn.length);
    
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.reset();
    md.update(bAll);
    String base64Str = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Don't edit your question to use the proposed solution in [the answer given below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68690424/6395627). That invalidates the answer. If the answer works for you then accept it. Otherwise explain that it doesn't work.

Comment: ok @Slaw. i have reverted it back to orignal. i try to update `password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to `password.getBytes("UTF-16")` yet still cant get the result.